# How can I write filtered results from a JSON file to a CSV file in Python?

Tags: python, json, csv

I am trying to make a program that can save the results of a filtered JSON file as a CSV. Right now my function only saves the keys of the JSON to the CSV file.

Ideally I want the function to take two arguments: column (key) it is searching in; and the item (value) it is searching for.

This is my current function:

```
def save_csv(key, value):
    with open('db.json') as json_file:
        info = json.load(json_file)
    test = info['data']

    csv_file = open('test.csv', 'w')
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    count = 0
    for e in test:
        if count == 0:
            header_csv = e.keys()
            csv_writer.writerow(header_csv)
            count += 1

    for e in key:
        if e == value:
            csv_writer.writerow(e.values())
    csv_file.close()
```

How could I change this function to make it save the filtered results in a CSV?

No matter what changes I try to make, it will only save the keys to the header of the CSV. None of the results I am filtering for will save to the CSV.

Comment: Please see [ask]. You must provide a [mcve]

Comment: @chuggles your function doesn't have sense...you need to filter by "key" or by "value"? what's the purpose of "key" and "value" input?

Comment: @NarcisseDoudieuSiewe I want to use be able to be able to search through different sections of the .json file. I wanted to pass specific parameters for the search (if I was searching for the color Orange in the data, I ideally thought the function could take the arguments: save_csv(color, orange). Does that make sense?

Comment: @chuggles give an example of json you want to filter it will help.

Comment: @NarcisseDoudieuSiewe here is the db.json I am trying to filter:

    "data": [
        {
            "name": "Alice",
            "age": 2,
            "color": "Black",
            "gender": "F"
        },
        {
            "name": "Callie",
            "age": 9,
            "color": "Orange",
            "gender": "F"
        },
        {
            "name": "Tommy",
            "age": 5,
            "color": "White",
            "gender": "M"
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def save_csv(key, value):
    with open('db.json') as json_file:
        info = json.load(json_file)
        test = info['data']
        with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
            csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
            for n,v in enumerate(test):
                if not n:
                    header_csv = e.keys()
                    csv_writer.writerow(header_csv)
                if key in v and v.get(key)==value:
                    csv_writer.writerow(e.values())
```

Comment: This does exactly what I want it to do! Thank you! However, when I save to the csv file there is a new line between each entry. Is there a way to change this so that there are no extra lines in between the data?

Comment: @chuggles see my update open the csv with a <newline=' '> to see what happens

Comment: This was the exact thing I needed! Could explain to me how you came to this solution?

Comment: @chuggles see the doc on the first example https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html  read it carefully

Comment: "data" is a list of dict, you need to iterate over that list and each time you will get the next dict. if in that dict "key" is one of the dict'key and the value of that dict'key equals the value's input, we save all the values for that dict into the csv...hope this help you

Comment: This was the exact clarification I needed. Thank you so much for all the help!